# Request Body is null in controller?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, .net-core

I'm calling a POST controller action using fetch, but in the controller, the body appears to be null.

Here's my fetch code snippet - this is in a .net core Vue project. It's a typescript file.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(this.newProduct);
console.log(data)

fetch('api/Product/AddNewProduct', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: data,
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
}).then(res => res.json())
       .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
       .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

And here's the request (and payload) as I can see it in Firefox:

[image: Request]

But in my .net core backend, when the API gets hit, I can't seem to get the value of the body or anything in the request.

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult AddNewProduct([FromBody] string body)
{
   Product newProduct;
   try
   {
     /*Added the below snippet for testing, not sure if actually necessary */
       using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
       {
           var requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
           // Do something
        }

        //Convert the request body to an object
        newProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(body);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
             return new BadRequestResult();
         }
```

Here, in my debugger, both `body` and `requestBody` are null. Any ideas?

Comment: don't try to read it again. its already being passed in your method parameters.

Comment: I'm only trying to read it for testing purposes, because the method parameter named body is null (per the last line of my post). Any ideas within that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.NET isn't seeing you passing a string, it sees a JSON because you pass the `Content-Type` header of `application/json` so it will try to deserialize it and map it to your request object. In your case, because your parameter is `string body` the parser tries to map the JSON object to your `string` and fails - so it passes `null`.

You can try and change the request to pass `text/plain` as the `content-type` (or remove the `content-type` header) or change your API parameter to the object you are sending:

```
public IActionResult AddNewProduct([FromBody] Product newProduct)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Amazing, this fixed it. I changed the API parameter to `Product`. Thank you! I didn't know .NET always automatically deserialized the json and tried to map it to the request object. I thought that was only a feature of the controllers that inherited from `ApiController`. Thanks again!

Comment: @iaacp No, .NET doesn't do this. ASP.NET Core does this. ASP.NET is a part of .NET. You need to research the differences.

Answer (score 2):

Add to headers Accept

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Accept': 'application/json',
},
```